# enabling iPhone to fetch and parse JSON?

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I don't know how to use the `output=json;callback=` for my iPhone App, appreciate for your help!

This [URL at tw.money.yahoo.com](http://tw.money.yahoo.com/YahooFundWeb/getSelectFund.aspx;c=BFC021;f=fn,fs,fd,fv,fcu,fr3,fr3s,fr6,fr6s,fr12,fr12s;s=fr3;o=desc;output=json;callback=cb_yfifcfl;.yts=1305541212;.yto=1305541272;.ys=cgDCC1FEHk1n7UgDdsWK23OKTtA-~B%22) returns this JSON:

```
{"ResultSet":{"totalResultsAvailable":"0",
              "Error":{"Code":400,
                       "Message":"\u67e5\u8a62\u53c3\u6578\u4e0d\u5408\u6cd5"}
             }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you get the response as a string, then it's very simple to parse - it just gets turned into NSDictionary and NSArray objects :)

Get the [touch-json framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) from github.

```
NSString *myJsonString = @"{'name':'Bob'}";
NSDictionary *dict = [myJsonString JSONValue];
```

After calling JSONValue on a string, dict will contain the key "name" that has the value "Bob".

Answer (score 0):

jsonkit

NSDictionary *listings = [[content objectFromJSONString] valueForKey:@"ResultSet"];