# json parser problem in iphone

Tags: iphone

http://www.bidapene.com/system/Mobile/json_newdata.php?data={"action":"login","mailID":"abc@gmail","pass":"admin"}

how to parse above url in json

Comment: possible duplicate of [enabling iPhone to fetch and parse JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020653/enabling-iphone-to-fetch-and-parse-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JSON Parser framework like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework).